# Who were the Bishops of Irkutsk after St. Innocent?

Tags: religion, russia, orthodoxism

The Irkutsk Orthodox diocese once administered a huge territory. Its founding bishop was [St. Innocent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocent_of_Irkutsk), succeeded by [Innocent (Nerunovich)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%28%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%29). Who else held the office before 1800?

Comment: Well, I don't know how reliable it is but if you go just to wiki page "Иркутская епархия" (Irkutsk diocese) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Иркутская_епархия you'll get the list (in russian) of all bishops ("Епископы") straight to the modern times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Russian church records, four others held office before 1800:

Ignatij Smola held office September 8 - October 1, 1721

Innokrntij (Nerunovich) held office November 25, 1732 - July 26, 1747.

Sophonij (Kristalevsky) held office April 18, 1753 - March 30, 1771

Michael (Mitkevich) held office August 2, 1772 - August 1, 1789

Benjamin (Bagranskij) held office September 9, 1789 — June 8, 1814

By the way, the Russian Orthodox Church considers not Ignatij I but [Varlaam Kossovsky](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%BC_(%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) to be the founder of this diocese.

Comment: Where did you get these records? Are they online? Did a priest tell you the names?

Comment: @RobertColumbia online: ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Иркутская_епархия

Comment: I must insist that Wikipedia is not "church records". Sounds like your mother considers the Irkutsk and Nerchinsk vicariate of the Tobolsk archdiocese to be the antecedent of the Irkutsk diocese, which is reasonable.